# Entity Framework 4.1 - Database First approach - How to find column names for primary key fields?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, primary-key, dbcontext

I'm using EF4.1 for DAL for an application, and I use DbContext template generator with POCP entities. The model is created from the database, so all the fields / PK's / FK's / relations are already defined in database. 
I need to find out in code which are the fields for the table for an entity.
Some tables might have a single field PK, while other might have compound PK. Whan I need is to have a method that will return me a List for an entity, with all field names composing the primary keys. It can be from DbContext, or from entity, doesn't matter. 
I could even customize the template to generate a method in POCO entity, as below:

```
public List<string> PrimaryKey()
    {
        List<string> pk = new List<string>();
        pk.AddRange(
            new string[] {"Field1", "Field2"});
        return pk;
    }
```

but I don't know how to find the field names composing the PK.
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and I modified the template to generate a property that returns this for me.

First I customized the template to generate strong typed names for field names (I hate using strings in code which can cause problems when refactoring). Then that is used to generate a property that returns primary key fields as List

Here are the changes to template (I used ADO.NET DbContext Template Generator, but for any other template it should be very similar):

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#>
<#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#> 
<#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{   
<#
WriteStrongTypedPropertyNames(code, entity);    // <-- Insert this
WritePrimaryKeyProperty(code, entity);          // <-- and this

// .....
```

And at the end of template file add:

```
<#+
void WriteStrongTypedPropertyNames(CodeGenerationTools code, EntityType entity)
{

#>  /// <summary>
    /// Strong typed property names
    /// </summary>
    public class PropertyNames
    {
<#+
    foreach (var property in entity.Properties)
    {
#>
        public const string <#=code.Escape(property)#> = "<#=property#>";
<#+
    }
#>
    }

<#+

}

void WritePrimaryKeyProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, EntityType entity)
{

#>    /// <summary>
    /// Returns primary key as List
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> PrimaryKey
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> pk = new List<string>();
            pk.AddRange(
                new string[] {                  
<#+
            foreach (var member in entity.KeyMembers)
            {
                string delim = "";
#>
                    <#=delim#> PropertyNames.<#=code.Escape(member.Name)#>
<#+
                delim=",";
            }
#>              });
            return pk;
        }
    }

<#+

}
#>
```

It generates a code as below in the entity:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Strong typed property names
    /// </summary>
    public class PropertyNames
    {
        public const string AppID = "AppID";
        public const string AppName = "AppName";
        public const string AppCode = "AppCode";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns primary key as List
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> PrimaryKey
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> pk = new List<string>();
            pk.AddRange(
                new string[] {                  
                     PropertyNames.AppID
                });
            return pk;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

I had a tough time trying to do almost the same thing, getting the primary key name and value at runtime when the type is unknown, from a DbContext. I was just get trying to implement an auditing scheme for deletes, and every solution i find involves superfluous code that I dont really understand. The EntityKey is not available from a DbContext, which is also confusing and annoying. The last 5 lines may save you 5 hours and 1 yr of baldness. I am not attempting this for Inserts, so if you do, you need to inspect those values carefully as they may be 0 or null.

```
foreach(var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>()) { 
...  
case EntityState.Deleted:
...  
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter.this).ObjectContext; //.this is a DbContext EntityKey
ek = oc.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity).EntityKey;
var tablename= ek.EntitySetName; 
var primaryKeyField = ek.EntityKeyValues[0].Key;     //assumes only 1 primary key var
primaryKeyValue = ek.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

stumbled across this post after having done something similar to @bzamfir.  I thought I would post what I did in hopes that it might alleviate some of the headaches that @Bill mentions that I have also experienced!
Using the DBContext, I also modified the Template.
1) Add `Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to the list of Imports already in the file
2) Add code to the Primitive Properties For Each Loop which adds the [KeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx) to the primary key properties.  It should look like:

```
For Each edmProperty As EdmProperty In primitiveProperties
    If ef.IsKey(edmProperty) Then  
       #><#= code.StringBefore("<KeyAttribute()>",Environment.NewLine & CodeRegion.GetIndent(region.CurrentIndentLevel + 2))#><#
End If
    WriteProperty(code, edmProperty)
Next
```

You can add this Extension Method to your code somewhere which will find the Primary Key based off of the KeyAttribute.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function FindPrimaryKeyProperty(Of T As Class)(context As DbContext, TEntity As T) As PropertyInfo
    Return TEntity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(Function(p) p.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(KeyAttribute), True).Count > 0)
End Function
```

I do recognize the point that this function will fail if you have more than one property flagged with KeyAttribute, however, for my situation this was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I just came across this solution that appears to work just fine and doesn't require any Template editing (+1).
http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

```
public static IEnumerable<string> KeysFor(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
{
    Contract.Requires(context != null);
    Contract.Requires(entityType != null);

    entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entityType);

    var metadataWorkspace =
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var objectItemCollection = 
    (ObjectItemCollection)metadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace);

    var ospaceType = metadataWorkspace
        .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
        .SingleOrDefault(t => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(t) == entityType);

    if (ospaceType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                "The type '{0}' is not mapped as an entity type.",
                entityType.Name),
            "entityType");
    }

    return ospaceType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
}
```